# ASP.NET Core publishing application by CLI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, command-line-interface

I have problem with publishing under IIS. i have been trying to automate publishing web app to the IIS by following cmd `dotnet publish App.csproj -c -o C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App.Web -c release`, but it just added it as folder, how to publish it as a Web Application, is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to **convert your folder to an application**.
To do so, just right click on it, and select "convert to application"
After that, as you're publishing a .netCore application, you will have to configure the application pool running that app, and **set "Framework version" to unmaged.** (and leave 
the pipeline to integrated)

[more information on hosting .NetCore on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

This is a one step configuration.
All you next publish should work fine.

**Some more explanations :**

.NetCore is platform agnostics, so it can't know you're deploying on IIS. 
When you deploy with legacy .net (4.xx) Visual studio has an IIS target for deployment, and did all the work.
With .net core, as it can also be run under linux, mac, etc.. the IIS specificities have been removed.

Comment: Ok, thanks when how to get it with legacy by CLI? I have *.bat in order to deploy it, could send me link to the documentation?

Comment: Hi, for legacy, you can fing some [extra info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment) & [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment)